# Regex to get multiple filters

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am new to Regex and trying to find all the files with .cs,.json etc.
But, I am just getting only 1 file extension i.e. only 1 filter value.

Code :

```
string ext = "json|cs|xml";
Regex RegEx = new Regex(@"<(Compile|Content|None) Include=\""([^\""]+." + ext + @")\""( /)?>",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = RegEx.Match(line); //Only takes json, does not take cs or xml
```

So, here it matches only json file.

Can anyone help me with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to add bracket around where you include your *ext* variable, as then the parser knows to match any of those options.

Currently what you have is going to match any character not including a double quote and the string *json* **OR** the string *cs* **OR** *xml*.  By adding the extra brackets (as below) you tell the parser to match any character not including the double quote and any of the extension you provide.

Replace

```
<(Compile|Content|None) Include=\""([^\""]+." + ext + @")\""( /)?>
```

with

```
<(Compile|Content|None) Include=\""([^\""]+.(" + ext + @"))\""( /)?>
```

PS. I find [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) very useful in debugging Regular Expressions. Not affiliated, just been using for quite a number of years.